# How can preview an document of envelopes showing in table and on click preview button

Tags: php, api, rest, docusignapi

I am using rest PHP APIs to get envelopes list of DocuSign and showing them on an HTML table, Now I have preview button where I want to preview the document, Does anybody knows how can I perform this task?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by making an API call to generate the URL from the server. You cannot store this URL and have it work all the time, it expires.
So you have to provide your own server's endpoint and your server make an API call to generate the URL and then redirect the user.
To generate a URL use this PHP method (in `EnvelopesAPI`):

```
createEnvelopeRecipientSharedView()
```